# Qt5 Error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При добавлении кода

```
JSParse *jsp = new JSParse();
jsp->sendRequest();
```

В main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "sql.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include "jsparse.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Sql *sql = new Sql();

    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.updateUsers(sql->users);

    JSParse *jsp = new JSParse();
    jsp->sendRequest();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Выдает ошибки:

```
main.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl JSParse::JSParse(void)" (??0JSParse@@QEAA@XZ) referenced in function main
main.obj:-1: ошибка: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl JSParse::sendRequest(void)" (?sendRequest@JSParse@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
debug\project01.exe:-1: ошибка: LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals
```

Файл jsparse.h

```
#ifndef JSPARSE_H
#define JSPARSE_H


class JSParse
{
public:
    JSParse();
    ~JSParse();

    void sendRequest();
};

#endif // JSPARSE_H
```

Файл jsparse.cpp

```
#include "jsparse.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebPage>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QUrlQuery>
#include <QWebSettings>
#include <QVariant>
#include <QJsonValue>
#include <QJsonDocument>
#include <QJsonObject>
#include <QVariantMap>
#include <QJsonArray>
#include <QEventLoop>

JSParse::JSParse()
{

}

JSParse::~JSParse()
{

}

void JSParse::sendRequest() {

    // create custom temporary event loop on stack
    QEventLoop eventLoop;

    // "quit()" the event-loop, when the network request "finished()"
    QNetworkAccessManager mgr;
    QObject::connect(&mgr, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), &eventLoop, SLOT(quit()));

    // the HTTP request
    QNetworkRequest req( QUrl( QString("http://time.jsontest.com/") ) );
    QNetworkReply *reply = mgr.get(req);
    eventLoop.exec(); // blocks stack until "finished()" has been called

    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError) {

        QString strReply = (QString)reply->readAll();

        //parse json
        qDebug() << "Response:" << strReply;
        QJsonDocument jsonResponse = QJsonDocument::fromJson(strReply.toUtf8());

        QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonResponse.object();

        qDebug() << "Time:" << jsonObj["time"].toString();
        qDebug() << "Date:" << jsonObj["date"].toString();

        delete reply;
    }
    else {
        //failure
        qDebug() << "Failure" <<reply->errorString();
        delete reply;
    }
}
```

Сам файл проекта:

```
QT       += core gui opengl sql webkit webkitwidgets network
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
TARGET = project01
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    glscene.cpp \
    sql.cpp \
    jsparse.cpp
HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    glscene.h \
    sql.h \
    jsparse.h
FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: Странно, не должно быть такого. Попробуйте для проверки того, компилируется ли файл `jsparse.cpp` на самом деле добавить в него какую-нибудь некомплируемую ерунду. И посмотрите, скомпилируется ли оно.

Comment: Запустите `qmake` и перестройте заново проект.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое бывает, хотя и не часто. У себя наблюдал, когда, например, убираешь, либо добавляешь наследование от `QObject` для произвольного класса уже после сборки проекта.

С другой стороны, это происходит не системно, то есть не каждый раз, поэтому истинной причины назвать не могу.

Полная пересборка проекта, включая этап с ***qmake*** не помогает.

Нужно сначала удалить все файлы в сборочной папке проекта, в том числе и `Makefile`. После этого сборка пройдёт без ошибок.

Comment: в QtCreator достаточно сделать очистку  с пересборкой, но сомневаюсь что это поможет.

Comment: @OlegUP Очистка с пересборкой не удаляет Makefile, поэтому и не поможет.

Comment: Возможно в .pro файле не прописаны нужные компоненты в секции QT, мне порой так же помогала перестановка местами порядка файлов включения. попробуйте подключить все qt'шные модули в jsparse.h

Comment: О чём Вы, @OlegUP ? Суть проблемы в том, что и в pro-файле и в коде всё написано верно, сам QtCreator по какой-то причине не обновляет Makefile. Возможно баг. Лишь после ручной ликвидации файлов в папке сборки, проект начинает собираться, как положено. При этом ничего не требуется менять в исходниках. Вероятно возможно иногда добиться ситуации, когда какая-нибудь правка pro-файла поспособствует выходу из ступора, но это также бывает и не срабатывает. Гарантированный способ - ручная зачистка от файлов папки сборки.

Comment: Да, я такое тоже встречал, когда помогает лишь полная ликвидация сборочной директории.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло удаление Makefile

Comment: @alexis031182 Всего лишь о том что мне порой помогало.

Comment: @OlegUP, я просто не понял, что Вы не мне отвечали. Всё нормально.